Manhwa in which the main character knows she'll die young, around 19-20
The main character is young but she knows she'll die around 19-20, due to the curse of her being born a female and females can't handle the 'power' or 'mana' that the family possesses. I remember something vividly in the manhwa .. she tells the knight that it's okay because she won't live long anyways and she has the ability to talk to deities in the walls or fairies.

Do you recall the hair colour of the main character? Also, how does reincarnation factor into the plot?

@logicdictates turns out i mixed two different manwha together at the end of my post. the girl died from cancer .. she a blonde or gold female. her birth she has an hourglass on her arm

Is this I Was Just Having Fun With the Time Limit...?

In my previous life, I had a limited time, but I reincarnated as someone with limited time again! Although this time too my life is limited, I got a life that lasts for 21 years. Even if I feel constrained, even breathing makes me happy! The family love I feel for the first time, and my mother asking me to grow up healthy. This life is a gift to me.


A Korean woman who'd fought cancer for most of her life dies and is reborn within a novel she'd read as Isabelle Bilotian, a baby princess in a family of swordsmen. She has a birthmark shaped like an hourglass on her right forearm, indicating that she'll die at the age of 21. As a girl, she isn't allowed to study swordsmanship like her father and brothers.




yes it is thank you so much

@nunu - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the grey check mark near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.
